# Robot Framework JMS Library Test

Tags: jms, robotframework

I've seen the only chance I have to make Robot tests consume from JMS queues is to use [this library](https://github.com/ilkkatoje/robotframework-jmslibrary), but I don't understand how it is supposed to work. When I install a Robot library I do it through pip, and then I start using it in my tests. But how am I supposed to install this one instead?

Comment: Long time ago it was quite common to run robot framework on top of Jython (python running on JVM) -- this library written for that, not for python side. Only way to get that particular lib to work would be to run that lib on remote library server but as that lib is quite old already, i wouldnt bother...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, there is not a way to use Robot with ActiveMQ?

Comment: From what I can tell this really doesn't have anything to do with ActiveMQ but instead with Robot and the library you're attempting to use. ActiveMQ is tangential. Therefore, I'm rewording your question to be more clear.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're using Python and you need to interact with ActiveMQ then you can just use STOMP. JMS is Java-centric so you can't use it from Python unless you have some kind of bridge between Python and Java. However, there are Python-based STOMP clients.

Comment: Using STOMP would be still okay but I did not find any library implementing such protocol to interact with ActiveMQ. I only found one implementing MQTT but it's not enough, since I'm using queues in ActiveMQ and the MQTT procotol did not support them.

Comment: How about [`stomp.py`](https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/)? Lots of folks use this with Python to interact with ActiveMQ.

Comment: @JustinBertram i dont know if there's a stomp bindings for robot framework and if op has to ask, it might be a stretch to add proper layer if there's any state to handle.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Robot. What exactly do you mean by "bindings"?

Comment: Robot Framework is python based automation tool that exposes "real" code as its own DSL .. Dropping a random python  library into robot framework might or might not work  depending on how it is implemented and if its not, essentially one would need to provide extra layer of python code to expose needed functionality to robot's "DSL".  Thus, suggestion just a python library, in most cases, is not enough to make it work from robot framework..  https://robotframework.org/ && https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries

Comment: @JustinBertram  ^ that was for you but somehow i missed your name ..

Comment: @rasjani, thanks much for the clarification!